# How to show all notification when using params in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to show in html my all notification. 
Value arrive in `res = response.json();` but in my site show only one notification, like in [image]
First  show from this code:

```
  public eventsbyserial(id: string): Observable<Notifications> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('serial_device', id);
    urlSearchParams.append('token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString();

    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.eventsbyserial), body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        console.log(res) // this show me all notifications
        if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
          return new Notifications(res.StatusDescription[0]);
        } else if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return new Notifications(null);
        }
      });
  }
```

Second show for this code:

```
 notificcationserial: Notifications[]=[];
  notif: Notifications;
     getalleventsserial() {
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
          params => {
            this.ns.eventsbyserial(params['id']).subscribe(
              notificcationserial => {
                this.notif = notificcationserial;
                console.log(this.notif) // show only one notification
              }
            );
          }
        );
      }
```

in html:

```
  <table *ngFor="let item of notificcationserial ">
          <tr >
              <td> {{item.alarmnumber}}</td>
              <td> {{item.acted}}</td>       
          </tr>
   </table>
```

Can you ask me what is the problem, any solution please?

UPDATE:

```
   if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
              return new Notifications(res.StatusDescription);
```

My result si like in photo: undefined

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you return only the first entry in your array and you put an array of StatusDescription in Notifications. That doesn't work.

```
[...]
    if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
      return new Notifications(res.StatusDescription[0]);
[...]
```

Do it this way.

```
public eventsbyserial(id: string): Observable<StatusDescription> {

[...]
    if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
      return res.StatusDescription;
[...]


notif: StatusDescription;
   getalleventsserial() {
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
        params => {
          this.ns.eventsbyserial(params['id']).subscribe(
            notificcationserial => {
              this.notif = notificcationserial;
              console.log(this.notif) // supposed to show 2 rows according to your example
            }
          );
        }
     );
   }
```

and in your HTML do this

```
  <table *ngFor="let item of notif">
          <tr >
              <td> {{item.alarmnumber}}</td>
              <td> {{item.acted}}</td>       
          </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Yes I try it, but my result is undefined. Like in my post update

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just now corrected my answer. Please, try again.

Comment: Now, show correctly in console. But in *ngFor="let item of notificcationserial  doesn't show. Thank you

Comment: Please have a look on my answer. There's another change referring to your HTML. If this was helpful to you, please mark this answer as solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that it works for you. You're welcome. :)